# how add pagination to author page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i try with WP-PageNavi plugin and instal the plugin and  palace `<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'type' => 'multipart' ) ); ?>` code in auther.php page under the loop but it shows the pagination but not wokring is there any settings i have to change in the options page in back end..??

Comment: or tell me another way of adding paginations in wordpress,i tried few plugins but it did't work out for me

Comment: need help can some one help this out..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this plug in wordpress hope it help you.

[Try this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/)

Comment: finally i get the work done without a plugin with php code thanks for the answers,and easiest way is to use theme that support pagination :D

Comment: @wordpresrox can you provide the PHP code that worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code after the loop:

```
<?php //Set Blog Reading Settings to XX for optimum view!!
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array( 'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                            'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
                            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                            'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                            'end_size'=> 1,
                            'mid_size'=> 10 ) );
?>
```

Hope it helps.